# Access variables dynamically in views on RoR3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, variables, dynamic, view

I have 10 instance variables called @foo_01, @foo_02, @foo_03,.. @foo_10 and I need to show the result sets of each variable on a page, these results must be displayed in a correct order with a rather lengthy algorithm that I rather not copy and paste 10 times changing the name of the variables as I find this extremely annoying, so I'm looking for a way to loop through the algorithm 10 times and dynamically access the variables, something sort of like this...

```
<% (1..10).each do |i| %>
  <% lengthy algorithm here %>
    <%= @foo_i .atribute.value %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't @foo be an array with your ten elements ? Then you could iterate over it with `@foo.each`.

Comment: Each @foo variable has disjoint result sets of the DB, so for logic purposes I rather keep them in separate variables.

Comment: Nothing forbids you to keep them separate and have said array (meaning you can have each `@foo_n` and a `@foos`, `@foo_array`, or whatever you want). It's the only pretty solution that comes to my mind.

Comment: Your right, unfortunately I have to use the algorithm exactly as it is (I'm working on a collaborative project, and I must reuse a function) and using an array means I must develop extra logic to determine from which variable came each result before I display them on the page.

Comment: I don't see what's the trouble, but why not. Ruby is dynamic and have a good set of introspection-related features, such as `#instances_variables`, which returns you the list of instance variables of the object, and `send(method)`, which calls `method` on object, allowing you to compute a string, then use it as a method name. I don't use them much, so you're gonna have to look for yourself, but if you don't want to/can't use an array, I think this is what you want.

Comment: Just found this searching in other posts, the `instance_variable_get` method should do the trick, I'm testing...

Comment: This works
`<% (1..10).each do |i| %>`
  `<% foo = instance_variable_get("@foo_0#{i}") %>`
`<% end %>`